# Fastest way to check if an object exists in Core Data or not?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data

I want to see if an object is persisted in Core Data or not. For example, I have Friends in Core Data, and I identify them by firstName. I can query core data to see if "George" is known. If the result set array contains more than zero objects, I know George is there. But Core Data loads the whole thing into memory, and I actually just want to know if George is stored or not.

How would I do it the most efficient way?

Comment: as @Jon mentioned, the official Apple Core Data documentation has a [chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) called 'Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently' that is easily overlooked and details several strategies to reduce memory footprint.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Setup a Core Data request and, instead of actually issuing the query, do the following:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request
                                                        error:&error];
if (!error) {
    return count;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

In practice, the method `countForFetchRequest:error:` returns the number of objects a given fetch request would have returned if it had been passed to `executeFetchRequest:error:`.

---

**Edit:** <sup>(by Regexident)</sup>

As **Josh Caswell** correctly commented, the correct way to handle errors is either this:

```
if (count == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    return 0;
}
return count;
```

or this (without error logging):

```
return (count != NSNotFound) ? count : 0;
```

Comment: and it should be more efficient because under the hood, the SQL engine should be doing and COUNT instead of a SELECT

Comment: Please note that the error handling here is incorrect; [as is generally the case in Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1), you must check the direct return value (`count`) before checking the error object. In this case, [the docs say](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) that a return of `NSNotFound` signals an error.

Comment: Massimo, how does this post answer the OP's question? The OP asked how he could determine if an object with a specific value i.e. "George" exists in the persisted store.

Comment: @Pavan, the question asked how to QUICKLY determine if an object exists, not how to return the object. Now, if the returned count associated to the query is zero (and there was no error), then you are sure that the object is not stored in the persistent store. Otherwise, you know the object (at least one) is there.

Comment: @MassimoCafaro you are right. If the object did exist, whats the quickest way to retrieve that 1 object then?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, definitely there is a better method. Setup a fetch request as usual, but, instead of actually executing it, simply ask for the number of objects it would have returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:

This can be done using

```
- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error;
```

Something like this:

```
- (int) numberOfContacts{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = yourManagedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [request release];

    if (!error){
        return count;
    }
    else
        return -1;

}
```

Comment: Yes but i have included full method and details.

Answer (score 11):

Update to SWIFT 5:

```
func checkIfItemExist(id: Int, type: String) -> Bool {

    let managedContext = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "DetailsEntity")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit =  1
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %d" ,id)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type == %@" ,type)

    do {
        let count = try managedContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
        if count > 0 {
            return true
        }else {
            return false
        }
    }catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use "AND" keyword in this case. NSPredicate(format: "id == %d AND type == %@", id, type)

Answer (score 7):

If the goal is to check if the object exist the solution is to implement this method in your Friend Model:

```
-(BOOL)exist
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = yourManagedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Friends" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName == %@", self.firstName]];    

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (count)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add this to MyModel.swift which is created in combo with MyModel+CoreDataProperties.swift, correct? And do you have a swift 2.0 version?? Oh and how do i call this function?  If(.......exist() == "yes")???

Comment: Oh and how would i check for a firstName,  for example Graham??

Comment: in my example, the method is in the model to get the firstname property. And don't forget to get your your managedObject. I have no example in swift .

Answer (score 6):

According to [Core Data Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html), you should not keep fetching to see if objects exists.

> There are many situations where you may need to find existing objects (objects already saved in a store) for a set of discrete input values. A simple solution is to create a loop, then for each value in turn execute a fetch to determine whether there is a matching persisted object and so on. This pattern does not scale well. If you profile your application with this pattern, you typically find the fetch to be one of the more expensive operations in the loop (compared to just iterating over a collection of items). Even worse, this pattern turns an O(n) problem into an O(n^2) problem.

**Edit March 16**:
I am not a db expert, but since people are asking for a more efficient solution, consider this set:

```
set1 = [apple, orange, banana, pineapple, lettuce]
```

We want to find out if `[mango, apple, grape]` is a part of this set.

The docs tell us not to iterate through [mango, apple, grape] and query the database looking for each item in turn because this is slow.

Consider this solution:

Hash the sets on the server side:

```
hash([mango, apple, grape]) = 234095dda321affe...
```

You can then bypass Core Data completely by asking the server if anything changed.
If the sets are different, you can then dump the objects in a managed object context and do a bulk save.

If you were really looking to see if each object in turn was a part of the set, you could do a fetch based on an indexed characteristic, such as "fruit with skin".

Comment: So I don't understand. What is the proposed solution? They're just saying it's wrong to check for the same data already existing? I think that's bogus...I know this reeaaally late, but I think this is still an issue.